# For Loop in (Findstr *.txt) Output Concatenated Between Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I have a code to print all string from multi files with below code:

```
for /f %%A in ('findstr /R "[0-9]" *.txt') do echo %%A
```

However the output concatenated when switching to different files:

```
C:\Users>echoarray.cmd
File1.txt:123
File1.txt:321
File1.txt:312File2.txt:456
File2.txt:654
File2.txt:546File3.txt:789
File3.txt:678
File3.txt:777File4.txt:123
File4.txt:789
File4.txt:999
```

What I want to do is, to put sum of all integer per row (from *.txt) into array then print output into one text file:

(Found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70388970/16158507) thanks to Gerhard)

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /R "[0-9]" *.txt') do (
   set /a %%a+=1
   set /a result[!%%a!]+=%%b
   echo result[!%%a!] > result.txt
)
```

Example results would be like below (from output of echoarray.cmd above):

```
1491                     ::my comment: first row result are from summation of 123+456+789+123
*continue for second row
*continue for third row
*continue for fourth row
```

I need your kind help to solve the concatenated output from findstr (hopefully someone can suggest me the correct solution for the array too).

P/S: I am using cmd on Windows 10

Comment: Are you forced to use cmd / batch files? When dealing with anything that requires coding, powershell is your friend, and code for something like this would be a lot cleaner -- and it opens you possibilities that would be impossible with cmd only.

Comment: Yes. The company I am working with removed all admin credential on staff's laptop. I had to automate a script so non-admin can run them. Also this is part of our country's regulation mandatory report submission. For us to spend for a proper tools, it may take a while due to procurement processes. This is the best way i can do to support. I am aware of powershell flexibility, but I may need time to start from basic. The only conding i am familiar (that support in windows) with is batch scripting. Why i dont request for IT to install tool? It is hard to guide non-IT personnel to got to IT dept.

Comment: You could preprocess your files using `for %%I in (*.txt) do (findstr /V "$" "%%~I" && >> "%%~I" echo/)`, so each file now should be terminated by a final line-break, given that there are only Windows-style ones (so carriage-return plus line-feed)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will satisfy your needs.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Line[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "}=" & For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=[]" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N /V "" "*.txt" 2^>NUL ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^\[[123456789][0123456789]*\][123456789][0123456789]*$"'
) Do Set /A Line[%%G] += %%H, } = %%G
If Not Defined } GoTo :EOF
(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Line[) 2>NUL"') Do Echo %%H) 1>"result.txt"
```

The above code uses `find.exe` to get the content of each `.txt` file, without tripping up on the lack of `CRLF` line endings. Then `findstr.exe` identifies only those lines which contain only a series of digits and passes those to the `Do` portion off the loop. `Set /A` then totals the content on a line number basis and prints to a `.txt` file only those results.

Please be aware that as this uses `Set /A` and has therefore ignored any lines where the first digit is a `0`. This prevents possible issues with octal arithmetic. You should also be aware that due to your requested output strings, there is no way of you determining  which totals belong to which lines, if any of your files contain some lines with non digit only characters in them.

Comment: Thank you! After working around with your code, I am able to produce the intended output. Sorry I am unable vote (+1) to your answer due to lack of reputation. And I tried comment out `SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and it's still works. The main script that I wrote only produce digits only and there will be no alphabet on them. Thanks a lot!